# Efficient import of semi structured text

Tags: matlab, parsing, import

I have multiple text files saved from a Tekscan pressure mapping system. I'm am trying to find the most efficient method for importing the multiple comma delimited matrices into one 3-d matrix of type `uint8`. I have developed a solution, which makes repeated calls to the MATLAB function `dlmread`. Unfortunately, it takes roughly 1.5 min to import the data. I have included the code below.

This code makes calls to two other functions I wrote, `metaextract` and `framecount` which I have not included as they aren't truly relevant to answering the question at hand.

Here are two links to samples of the files I am using.

[The first is a shorter file with 90 samples](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NtC-nG0-NodGw-uEUKbEL8AGUZx6Euaf/view?usp=sharing)

[The second is a longer file with 3458 samples](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GU9b3SAbY6l-4ITgJbnz027ifWYbhxbB/view?usp=sharing)

Any help would be appreciated

```
function pressureData = tekscanimport
% Import TekScan data from .asf file to 3d matrix of type double.

[id,path] = uigetfile('*.asf'); %User input for .asf file
if path == 0 %uigetfile returns zero on cancel
    error('You must select a file to continue')
end

path = strcat(path,id); %Concatenate path and id to full path

% function calls
pressureData.metaData = metaextract(path);
nLines = linecount(path); %Find number of lines in file
nFrames = framecount(path,nLines);%Find number of frames

rowStart = 25; %Default starting row to read from tekscan .asf file
rowEnd = rowStart + 41; %Frames are 42 rows long
colStart = 0;%Default starting col to read from tekscan .asf file
colEnd = 47;%Frames are 48 rows long
pressureData.frames = zeros([42,48,nFrames],'uint8');%Preallocate for speed

f = waitbar(0,'1','Name','loading Data...',...
    'CreateCancelBtn','setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1)');
setappdata(f,'canceling',0);

for i = 1:nFrames %Loop through file skipping frame metadata
    if getappdata(f,'canceling')
        break
    end
    waitbar(i/nFrames,f,sprintf('Loaded %.2f%%', i/nFrames*100));

    %Make repeated calls to dlmread
    pressureData.frames(:,:,i) = dlmread(path,',',[rowStart,colStart,rowEnd,colEnd]);
    rowStart = rowStart + 44;
    rowEnd = rowStart + 41;
end
delete(f)
end
```

Comment: The first advice would be to not repeatedly call `dlmread` in a loop on the same file. There are many overheads every time `dlmread` is trying to find your line numbers etc ... You should just read the full file (or at least all the frames) in one go, then parse your frames in Matlab memory, it will be a lot faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try. This code opens your big file in 3.6 seconds on my PC. The trick is to use `sscanf` instead of the `str2double` and `str2number` functions.

```
clear all;tic
fid = fopen('tekscanlarge.txt','rt');
%read the header, stop at frame
header='';
l = fgetl(fid);
while length(l)>5&&~strcmp(l(1:5),'Frame')
    header=[header,l,sprintf('\n')];
    l = fgetl(fid);
    if length(l)<5,l(end+1:5)=' ';end
end
%all data at once
dat = fread(fid,inf,'*char');
fclose(fid);
%allocate space
res = zeros([48,42,3458],'uint8');
%get all line endings
LE = [0,regexp(dat','\n')];
i=1;
for ct = 2:length(LE)-1 %go line by line
    L = dat(LE(ct-1)+1:LE(ct)-1);
    if isempty(L),continue;end
    if all(L(1:5)==['Frame']')
        fr = sscanf(L(7:end),'%u');
        i=1;
        continue;
    end
    % sscan can only handle row-char with space seperation.
    res(:,i,fr) = uint8(sscanf(strrep(L',',',' '),'%u'));
    i=i+1;
end
toc
```

Does anyone knows of a faster way to convert than `sscanf`? Because it spends the majority of time on this function (2.17 seconds). For a dataset of 13.1MB I find it very slow compared to the speed of the memory.

Found a way to do it in 0.2 seconds that might be usefull for others as well. 
This mex-file scans through a list of char values for numbers and reports them back. Save it as `mexscan.c` and run `mex mexscan.c`.

```
#include "mex.h" 
/* The computational routine */
void calc(unsigned char *in, unsigned char *out, long Sout, long Sin)
{
    long ct = 0;
    int newnumber=0; 
    for (int i=0;i<Sin;i+=2){
        if (in[i]>=48 && in[i]<=57) { //it is a number
            out[ct]=out[ct]*10+in[i]-48;
            newnumber=1;
        } else { //it is not a number
            if (newnumber==1){
                ct++;
                if (ct>Sout){return;}
            }
            newnumber=0;
        }
    }    
}

/* The gateway function */
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    unsigned char *in;             /* input vector */
    long Sout;                     /* input size of output vector */
    long Sin;                      /* size of input vector */
    unsigned char *out;            /* output vector*/

    /* check for proper number of arguments */
    if(nrhs!=2) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nrhs","two input required.");
    }
    if(nlhs!=1) {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:nlhs","One output required.");
    }
    /* make sure the first input argument is type char */
    if(!mxIsClass(prhs[0], "char"))  {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","Input matrix must be type char.");
    }
    /* make sure the second input argument is type uint32 */
    if(!mxIsClass(prhs[0], "char"))  {
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("MyToolbox:arrayProduct:notDouble","Input matrix must be type char.");
    }

    /* get dimensions of the input matrix */
    Sin = mxGetM(prhs[0])*2;
    /* create a pointer to the real data in the input matrix  */
    in = (unsigned char *) mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    Sout = mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);

    /* create the output matrix */
    plhs[0] = mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,Sout,mxUINT8_CLASS,0);

    /* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
    out = (unsigned char *) mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

    /* call the computational routine */
    calc(in,out,Sout,Sin);
}
```

Now this script runs in 0.2 seconds and returns the same result as the previous script.

```
clear all;tic
fid = fopen('tekscanlarge.txt','rt');
%read the header, stop at frame
header='';
l = fgetl(fid);
while length(l)>5&&~strcmp(l(1:5),'Frame')
    header=[header,l,sprintf('\n')];
    l = fgetl(fid);
    if length(l)<5,l(end+1:5)=' ';end
end
%all data at once
dat = fread(fid,inf,'*char');
fclose(fid);
S=[48,42,3458];
d = mexscan(dat,uint32(prod(S)+3458));
d(1:prod(S(1:2))+1:end)=[];%remove frame numbers
d = reshape(d,S);
toc
```

Comment: I would agree that it does seem slow, but I can't complain about an increase in speed of 48 times.

Comment: `sscanf` is rather low-level already so beating it will be difficult. `textscan` can also be used on string (not only on file) and is said to be fast so you could try it, but I suspect the inner mechanics of `textscan` for converting string to number will be the same than `sscanf` so I wouldn't expect a big difference. Could be worth a try though ...

Comment: Yes, I tried `textscan` before I tried `sscanf`. It was slower than `sscanf`.

Comment: So I wrote a mex-file that exctracts all numbers from a char variable. This method is fast.

Comment: @BradDay: do you know the size of your dataset in advance?

Comment: @Gelliant , Yes I know the size in advance.

Comment: @BradDay: Good, then the 0.2 second method should work.